# Is there a way to extend AlertDialog and then totally take control of its appearance?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm looking at the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

And all their examples seem to overlook the developer's potential desire to totally alter the appearance and/or positioning of the OK | Cancel buttons.

I feel like the solution with the DialogFragment comes close, but still there's no obvious way for me to define what View in my activity should BE the OK button, so that I can easily attach the callback to it.

What am I missing? Or is it really not possible to manipulate the appearance and position of the buttons in anything that extends AlertDialog or DialogFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dialog` and add your own custom layout to it and control the appearance of every view in it. Here is an example how you can do this :

```
final Dialog alert = new Dialog(FingerPaintActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // no title 
alert.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialogAnimation; // this is used for custom animation when dialog is showing and hiding 
alert.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stamps, null)); // here is your custom layout
alert.getWindow().setLayout(width-50, (height-100)); // set height / width
```

and you can use set listeners to your views (for example a button) like this :

```
Button myOkBtn = (Button) alert.findViewById(R.id.myOkBtn);
myOkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising.  So, the only thing I'm not 100% clear on is what you mean by `FingerPaintActivity.this`, I'm assuming that FingerPaintActivity is the one that's launching this dialog (the Activity currently in the foreground), what's the difference between passing in `this` vs. `FingerPaintActivity.this`?

Comment: It is the context needed to create the `Dialog`. This piece of code was placed in `OnClickListener`, that's why you can't use only `this` and I needed to declare the `Activity's` context. That's the reason. You can use only `this` in your situation.